# How to make object type in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am using typescript. And I want to make the specific type of keys in object.
But this doesn't work at all.  
It gives me some error as below.

> Class 'Config' incorrectly implements interface 'IConfig'.
>     Property 'DBConfig' is private in type 'Config' but not in type 'IConfig'.
>
> Member 'DBConfig' implicitly has an 'any' type.

```
interface IConfig {
  DBConfig: {
    username: string;
    password: string;
    database: string;
    host: string;
    dialect: string;
  };
}

class Config implements IConfig {
  private DBConfig;

  constructor() {}

  public getDBConfig(environment: string): Object {
    switch (environment) {
      case "local":
        this.DBConfig = {
          username: "root",
          password: "1234",
          database: "test",
          host: "127.0.0.1",
          dialect: "mysql",
        };
        break;
    }
    return this.DBConfig;
  }
}

export { Config };
```

could you recommend some advice for this case? Thank you so much for reading it.

Comment: try `object` (lowercase), in your case I would suggest to be more precise if it's possible and to use `IConfig['DBConfig']`.

Comment: to implement an interface memeber you must make it public .. remove `private` from ` private DBConfig;`

Comment: The error message gives you two important things: you do not have a public `DBConfig` to match the interface and that your implementation's `DBConfig` does not have a type specified (the type needs to match the type in the interface and it needs to be public to count as implementing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Interfaces describe the public side of the class, rather than both the public and private side. This prohibits you from using them to check that a class also has particular types for the private side of the class instance.

Source: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#interfaces-extending-classes